# Mount CIF with permission for 2 users

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I mount a drive with this command in fstab

```
//analyticstest/datadrive cifs vers=2.1,credentials=/home/ccruzado/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

The problem is that I have 2 folder within the mounted unit to which I wish to give different permissions, for default the permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Aug 26 21:59 tomcat7
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Aug 27 14:48 postgres
```

I want the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 0 Aug 26 21:59 tomcat7
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres 0 Aug 27 14:48 postgres
```

It's possible? I wanted to change permissions with chmod but is doesn't work, when I add the two gid or uid change permissions for both folders, i did this with the command:

```
//analyticstest.file.core.windows.net/prueba /datadrive cifs vers=2.1,credentials=/home/ccruzado/.smbcredentials,uid=tomcat7,uid=postgres,gid=tomcat7,gid=postgres 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create a group (Or add both users to a X group) & add together users to group.
Add permissions to group.

Comment: Thx @pata_de_jaguar, i do this and I add: "dir_mode=0771,file_mode=0771,nounix", but I want to know if is possible to do what I said in my question